# multiple paths in git alternate file?

Tags: git

I suspect this isn't possible I've done a ton of searching but haven't found anything about it but I figure I'll ask.

In a nut shell
Is it possible to setup multiple paths in the alternates file in git?

The long version, what I'm trying to achieve
On my nas I have a git server (gitblit), one of the repos hosted there I want to keep an unpacked copy in another location without disturbing the repo as stored by gitblit, to keep the overhead low I cloned the repo with the -s option to setup the alternates file. I did this logged in to the nas with ssh so all paths were local /volume1/share/etc. Most of the checkouts will be issued with onboard scripts so this is what I want but I would sometimes like to look at the repo thru the shares on my windows pc, obviously windows doesn't have a clue where /volume1 is. Is there anyway to setup multiple alternate files or multiple paths in the one file. This way the Linux os on board has 1 path and with windows access can look it up thru the nas's fixed ip address?

Answer (score 3):

> In a nut shell Is it possible to setup multiple paths in the alternates file in git?

It says so right in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html):

> objects/info/alternates
>
>   This file records paths to alternate object stores that this object store borrows objects from, one pathname per line. Note that not only native Git tools use it locally, but the HTTP fetcher also tries to use it remotely; this will usually work if you have relative paths (relative to the object database, not to the repository!) in your alternates file, but it will not work if you use absolute paths unless the absolute path in filesystem and web URL is the same. See also
>   *objects/info/http-alternates*
>   .

Answer (score 2):

Note that with Git 2.21 (Q1 2019, 1+ year later):

- the "`alternate_object_database`" is renamed "`object_directory`",
- the **alternates paths are handled the same as the main object dir**.

See [commit 7317aa7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7317aa7153c063a01750cda625e1a4580af89ef3) (22 Nov 2018), and [commit 97b2fa0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97b2fa08b6b9ee3ebd927bbc208bf5223e5ac849), [commit 61c7711](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61c7711cfea250e7ed06839c07189df47fb42de7), [commit 3a2e082](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a2e08245cfccd932bb3ff78521e07d4a38c2834), [commit f0eaf63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0eaf638195a6510254b075026dcad955b8b607d), [commit f3f043a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3f043a103b7a7da57272ecf3252bda6089e41ae), [commit b69fb86](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b69fb867b4bb9e30e705d2176fe8a0a90b208325), [commit 263db40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/263db403face43927c2eb545a2e6ebb39aae4239), [commit b2ac148](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2ac148faecc95243ed8da0b75f63966d828c802), [commit 4d0984b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d0984bebc5fc5662d2891ee41f7d49c32488744) (12 Nov 2018) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3b2f8a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b2f8a02fa9a9e68d5215828e1d97bb4f6996976), 04 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### rename "alternate_object_database" to "object_directory"

> In preparation for unifying the handling of alt odb's and the normal repo object directory, let's use a more neutral name.
> This patch is purely mechanical, swapping the type name, and converting any variables named "`alt`" to "`odb`". There should be no functional change, but it will reduce the noise in subsequent diffs.

And:

> ### handle alternates paths the same as the main object dir

> When we generate loose file paths for the main object directory, the caller provides a buffer to `loose_object_path` (formerly `sha1_file_name`).
> The callers generally keep their own static buffer to avoid excessive reallocations.
>
> But for alternate directories, each struct carries its own scratch buffer. This is needlessly different; let's unify them.
>
> We could go either direction here, but this patch moves the alternates struct over to the main directory style (rather than vice-versa).
>
> Technically the alternates style is more efficient, as it avoids rewriting the object directory name on each call.
> But this is unlikely to matter in practice, as we avoid reallocations either way (and nobody has ever noticed or complained that the main object directory is copying
> a few extra bytes before making a much more expensive system call).

---

That has an effect on managing those loose objects on the managing path:

> ### sha1-file: use loose object cache for quick existence check

> In cases where we expect to ask `has_sha1_file()` about a lot of objects that we are not likely to have (e.g., during fetch negotiation), we already use `OBJECT_INFO_QUICK` to sacrifice accuracy (due to racing with a simultaneous write or repack) for speed (we avoid re-scanning the pack directory).
>
> However, even checking for loose objects can be expensive, as we will `stat()` each one. On many systems this cost isn't too noticeable, but `stat()` can be particularly slow on some operating systems, or due to network filesystems.
>
> Since the `QUICK` flag already tells us that we're OK with a slightly stale answer, we can use that as a cue to look in our in-memory cache of each object directory. That basically trades an in-memory binary search for a stat() call.
>
> Note that it is possible for this to actually be *slower*. We'll do a full `readdir()` to fill the cache, so if you have a very large number of loose objects and a very small number of lookups, that `readdir()` may end up more expensive.
>
> This shouldn't be a big deal in practice.
> If you have a large number of reachable loose objects, you'll already run into performance problems (which you should remedy by repacking).
> You may have unreachable objects which wouldn't otherwise impact performance. Usually these would go away with the prune step of "`git gc`", but they may be held for up to 2 weeks in the default configuration.
>
> So it comes down to how many such objects you might reasonably expect to have, how much slower is readdir() on `N` entries versus `M` stat() calls (and here we really care about the syscall backing `readdir()`, like `getdents()` on Linux, but I'll just call this `readdir()` below).
>
> - If `N` is much smaller than `M` (a typical packed repo), we know this is a big win (few readdirs() followed by many uses of the resulting cache).
> - When `N` and `M` are similar in size, it's also a win.
>   We care about the latency of making a syscall, and `readdir()` should be giving us many values in a single call. How many?
>
> On Linux, running "`strace -e getdents ls`" shows a 32k buffer getting 512
> entries per call (which is 64 bytes per entry; the name itself is 38
> bytes, plus there are some other fields).
> So we can imagine that this is always a win as long as the number of loose objects in the repository is a factor of 500 less than the number of lookups you make.
>
> It's hard to auto-tune this because we don't generally know up front how many lookups we're going to do. But it's unlikely for this to perform significantly
> worse.

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), this allows a performance tweak on "`git push`" into a repository with many refs that point at objects we have never heard of.

See [commit 5cf7a17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cf7a17dfbe60ea3cfb32ace7264edc3ad97611b) (27 Nov 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 403ac13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/403ac1381cc8bed5e02963a955f2a2a626620eaa), 06 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`send-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cf7a17dfbe60ea3cfb32ace7264edc3ad97611b): use `OBJECT_INFO_QUICK` to check negative objects
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When pushing, we feed pack-objects a list of both positive and negative objects. The positive objects are what we want to send, and the negative objects are what the other side told us they have, which we can use to limit the size of the push.
>
> Before passing along a negative object, `send_pack()` will make sure we actually have it (since we only know about it because the remote mentioned it, not because it's one of our refs).
> So it's expected that some of these objects will be missing on the local side.
> But looking for a missing object is more expensive than one that we have: it triggers `reprepare_packed_git()` to handle a racy repack, plus it has to explore every alternate's loose object tree (which can be slow if you have a lot of them, or have a high-latency filesystem).
>
> This isn't usually a big problem, since repositories you're pushing to don't generally have a large number of refs that are unrelated to what the client has. But there's no reason such a setup is wrong, and it currently performs poorly.
>
> We can fix this by using `OBJECT_INFO_QUICK,` which tells the lookup code that we expect objects to be missing.
> Notably, it will not re-scan the packs, and it will use the loose cache from [61c7711cfe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61c7711cfea250e7ed06839c07189df47fb42de7) ("`sha1-file`: use loose object cache for quick existence check", 2018-11-12, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b2f8a02fa9a9e68d5215828e1d97bb4f6996976) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecbdaf0899161c067986e9d9d564586d4b045d62)).
>
> The downside is that in the rare case that we race with a local repack, we might fail to feed some objects to `pack-objects`, making the resulting push larger.
> But we'd never produce an invalid or incorrect push, just a less optimal one. That seems like a reasonable tradeoff, and we already do similar things on the fetch side (e.g., when marking COMPLETE commits).

---

Before Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), once we start running, we assumed that the list of alternate object databases would never change.
Now: hook into the machinery used to update the list of packfiles during runtime to update this list as well.

See [commit e2d003d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2d003dbedf05906c0cc22493a96124c94521973) (08 Mar 2023) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0717a42](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0717a424a723201c4b77da3638764c70819c3f63), 19 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`object-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2d003dbedf05906c0cc22493a96124c94521973): reprepare alternates when necessary
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> When an object is not found in a repository's object store, we sometimes call `reprepare_packed_git()` to see if the object was temporarily moved into a new pack-file (and its old pack-file or loose object was deleted).
> This process does a scan of each pack directory within each odb, but does not reevaluate if the odb list needs updating.
>
> Extend `reprepare_packed_git()` to also reprepare the alternate odb list by setting `loaded_alternates` to zero and calling `prepare_alt_odb()`.
> This will add newly-discoverd odbs to the linked list, but will not duplicate existing ones nor will it remove existing ones that are no longer listed in the alternates file.
> Do this under the object read lock to avoid readers from interacting with a potentially incomplete odb being added to the odb list.
>
> If the alternates file was edited to *remove* some alternates during the course of the Git process, Git will continue to see alternates that were ever valid for that repository.
> ODBs are not removed from the list, the same as the existing behavior before this change.
> Git already has protections against an alternate directory disappearing from the filesystem during the lifetime of a process, and those are still in effect.
>
> This change is specifically for concurrent changes to the repository, so it is difficult to create a test that guarantees this behavior is correct.
> I manually verified by introducing a `reprepare_packed_git()` call into `get_revision()` and stepped into that call in a debugger with a parent '[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e2d003dbedf05906c0cc22493a96124c94521973/Documentation/git-log.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> process.
> Multiple runs of `prepare_alt_odb()` kept `the_repository->objects->odb` as a single-item chain until I added a `.git/objects/info/alternates` file in a different process.
> The next run added the new odb to the chain and subsequent runs did not add to the chain.

---

Note that Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [batch 13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2a540e432fe5dff3cfa9d3bf7ca56db2ad12ebb9) fixes a bug where fetching via protocol v0 over Smart HTTP transport sometimes failed to correctly auto-follow tags.

See [commit fba732c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fba732c462107a6e8a92577cae1d64a8cc149879) (23 Jan 2024) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cbcf619](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbcf61990f09ccaf7560832274fa39b24d09d12e), 02 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`transport-helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fba732c462107a6e8a92577cae1d64a8cc149879): re-examine object dir after fetching
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> This patch fixes a bug where fetch over http (or any helper) using the v0 protocol may sometimes fail to auto-follow tags.
> The bug comes from [61c7711](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61c7711cfea250e7ed06839c07189df47fb42de7) ("`sha1-file`: use loose object cache for quick existence check", 2018-11-12, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b2f8a02fa9a9e68d5215828e1d97bb4f6996976) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecbdaf0899161c067986e9d9d564586d4b045d62)).
> But to explain why (and why this is the right fix), let's take a step back.
>
> After fetching a pack, the object database has changed, but we may still hold in-memory caches that are now out of date.
> Traditionally this was just the `packed_git` list, but [61c7711](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61c7711cfea250e7ed06839c07189df47fb42de7) started using a loose-object cache, as well.
>
> Usually these caches are invalidated automatically.
> When an expected object cannot be found, the low-level object lookup routines call `reprepare_packed_git()`, which re-scans the set of packs (and thanks to some preparatory patches ahead of [61c7711](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61c7711cfea250e7ed06839c07189df47fb42de7), throws away the loose object cache).
> But not all calls do this! In some cases we expect that the object might not exist, and pass `OBJECT_INFO_QUICK` to tell the low-level routines not to bother re-scanning.
> And the tag auto-following code is one such caller, since we are asking about oids that the other side has (but we might not have locally).
>
> To deal with this, we explicitly call `reprepare_packed_git()` ourselves after fetching a pack; this goes all the way back to [48ec3e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48ec3e5c073e97c15842ac16523444786b37774e) ("Incorporate fetched packs in future object traversal", 2008-06-15, Git v1.6.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01d8ff70f40d8be3c4e2efb245ffc3d013b7fcbf)).
> But that only helps if we call `fetch_pack()` in the main fetch process.
> When we're using a transport helper, it happens in a separate sub-process, and the parent process is left with old values.
> So this is only a problem with protocols which require a separate helper process (like http).
>
> This patch fixes it by teaching the parent process in the transport helper relationship to make that same reprepare call after the helper finishes fetching.
>
> Why does the included test use "--depth 1"? This is important because without it, we happen to invalidate the cache as a side effect of other parts of the fetch process.